# How to handle unauthorized requests with nodejs/passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

As per [the documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), if I was handling authentication requests like so, I would be able to capture successful attempts.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

But, like the documentation says:

> *By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked.* If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the req.user property will be set to the authenticated user.

How can I handle the unauthorized login attempt?

I know I can handle it with custom middleware but is there a better way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should have a look at the **Custom Callback** section in [**passport docs**](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) which explains about how to override the built in behavior of handling an authentication request. You can write a custom callback which will serve as the `done` function that you are invoking from the Strategy.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  /* look at the 2nd parameter to the below call */
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Look at the second parameter to the `passport.authenticate` call, which will serve as the `done` function that you invoke from the local strategy.

See the `done` function invoked in the code below, which is the local strategy that you define for passport. You can call the `done` function with various available parameters like `err`, `user`, `info` set from the strategy according to the response from API call or db operation. These parameters will be processed by the above function definition in the `passport.authenticate` call.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    /* see done being invoked with different paramters
       according to different situations */
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: If I use the second snippet (`passport.use ..`) then I do not need the first one`app.get..`),right? Where would I define the password and username in the second snippet?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I didn't want the 401 error (which is the "default behavior"), 
and I just wanted a simple redirect  if the user wasn't authorized. The simple `{ failureRedirect: '/login' }` worked for me, as explained on the [PassportJS documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) (in the "Overview" and the "Redirects" header)

> Despite the complexities involved in authentication, code does not
>   have to be complicated.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect:'/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

> In this case, the redirect options override the default behavior. Upon
>   successful authentication, the user will be redirected to the home
>   page. If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
>   login page for another attempt.

The accepted answer gives you more flexibility. But this answer is a bit simpler.

I'm pretty sure "failure" includes the case where there would be no user: `if (!user)`, but I'm *not* sure if failure includes the error case or not: `if (err)`, as seen in the [accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236511/1175496)